# JavaScript issue opening a new page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to navigate to a different page once submit button is clicked. Since I have to do some operations I have to do it via a JavaScript function.

But it's not working, I'm getting the both alerts but it's not navigating to the index.html ( which is in same level as current page), even url is not changing .
Can you help me to fix it ?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function recordPickupDetails1(){
                alert("calling");
                location.href='index.html';
                alert("calling after");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body> 
    <form onsubmit="recordPickupDetails1()">  
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h2>Pickup Details</h2>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" pattern="[A-Za-z ]*"  required />
            </li>
            <li>                
                <button  class="submit" type="submit" > Next </button> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form> 
</body>
```

Comment: Try with this: location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com"); http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `location.href = 'index.html'` to `window.location.href ='index.html'`

Here is a JSBin with working code.

http://jsbin.com/giruweqaba/edit?html,js

http://jsbin.com/giruweqaba

Comment: Thanks, but Still not working , I tried with this window.location.href='index.html';

Comment: Try with this:  `location.replace("index.html");` as stated by @Akul above

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that as well. Is this working for you ?

Comment: Let me get a JSFiddle set up and check this out.

Comment: @Elike I have added a JSBin with working code, check it out. You may need to try adding in a full url?

Answer (score 2):

Add action to your form. You don`t need javascript.

```
<form action="index.html">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vm3m74q1/5/

fiddle is updated, so you can use javascript to do something before you submit.

Comment: Thanks but I need to do some operations as well inside the js function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want do some operation and then decide if submit should by done or not try:

```
<script>
function recordPickupDetails1(){

    alert("calling");
    // if you want stop function and submit use:
    return false;
    alert('call2');
}
</script>
<from action="index.htm" onsubmit="return recordPickupDetails1()">
```